# C++ Unable to move unique_ptr with universal references

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, unique-ptr, universal-reference

Consider this code:

```
template<typename T>
T mov(T&& t){
   return std::move(t);
}

int main(){
   std::unique_ptr<int> a = std::unique_ptr<int>(new int());
   std::unique_ptr<int> b = mov(a);
}
```

The `mov` function should simply take a universal reference and return it by value but by `move`ing it instead of copying. Thus, no copying should be involved when calling this method. Consequently, it should be fine to call such a function with a `unique_ptr` which can only be moved. However, this code does not compile: I receive the error:

```
test.cpp:24:34: error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = int; _Dp = std::default_delete<int>]’
    std::unique_ptr<int> b = mov(a);
```

So it seems that C++ tries to invoke `unique_ptr`s copy constructor which is of course deleted. But why does a copy happen here? How can I get this code to compile?

Comment: That `std::unique_ptr<int> b = mov(std::move(a));` *works* should be a hint to what is wrong.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I especially want to avoid the `move` here. Otherwise, I would not need a universal reference but an rvalue reference. The point of a universal refence **is** that it can also hold a usual lvalue reference.

Comment: Then I'm not seeing the end-game. What do you think is in `a` while within `mov` *without* moving per my comment? The `T&&` isn't promoted to an [xvalue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) as you've written it. It needs to be to be moved (or I am just not seeing it, which wouldn't be the first time).

Comment: @WhozCraig: If I call `mov` with an rvalue, then `a` is `int&&` inside `mov`, if I call `mov` with an lvalue, then `a` is `int&` inside `mov`. [Here](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) is an explanation of the behviour.

Comment: *Exactly*. So how do you expect passing simply `a` will deduce to an xvalue heading into `mov` ? Last I checked only `prvalue` or `xvalue` are movable, and `mov(a)` exhibits *neither* of those.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I somehow managed to solve the problem. Check out my answer.

Comment: That would do it. And not surprisingly, is nearly identical to `std::move` on my implementation (clang 3.4). gratz!

Comment: @WhozCraig: Yeah, it is semantically identical, but you save the `std::move` on every function call. In a scenario where you are always handling `unique_ptrs` and it is clear that every function consumes them, adding allways `move` to every call is cumbersome and can be avoided with this trick.

Comment: Ok I buy that. was trying to understand what the possible use case was until that comment. thanks!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the error is in the return type of `mov`

The code should read

```
#include <utility>
#include <memory>
template<typename T>
typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& mov(T&& t){
   return std::move(t);
}

int main(){
   std::unique_ptr<int> a = std::unique_ptr<int>(new int());
   auto b = mov(a);
}
```

The question hinted at a return by value scenario, this also compiles. I'm not sure if it will work in your situation;

```
template<typename T>
typename std::remove_reference<T>::type mov(T&& t){
   return std::move(t);
}
```

Comment: I figured out the same right before you, but thanks for your answer anyway :)

Comment: The solution was obvious to me, what's not obvious to me is the explanation for why the original is wrong.

Comment: @gexicide I see it now. Synchronous typing. Nice little problem thought. I think the reference collapsing is going to get people for some time. It's bitten me a few times already.

Comment: @Niall: Yes, it is indeed quite vexing. I thought I had understood all that rvalue/move semantics stuff, but there are hidden problems lurking everywhere...

Comment: @gexicide If the return-by-value was what was required, `typename std::remove_reference<T>::type mov(T&& t)` also seems to compile.

Comment: @Niall: Why does that work? Shouldn't the type of `std::remove_reference<T>::type` be simply `T` and thus identical to the version in my question?

Comment: @gexicide. I reason, it returns an unnamed value, an rvalue. The original was templated to `T` which is deduced to be `T&`, the `std::remove_ref` strips the deduced `&` and you are left with `T`

Answer (score 3):

I have finally found a working solution. I think the problem is the return by value which will trigger a copy. Instead I need a return by rvalue reference; then a move will be conducted automatically. First I tried this:

```
template<typename T>
T&& mov(T&& t){
   return std::move(t);
}
```

But now, the problem is that the return type `T&&` is a *universal reference*, not an rvalue reference. Thus, when calling the function with an lvalue, the actual signature is `T& mov(T& t)`. Because of that, its body will not compile because I cannot `std::move` to an lvalue reference. This was exactly what happend, here is the error:

```
test.cpp:18:22: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 

‘std::unique_ptr<int>&’ from an rvalue of type ‘std::remove_reference<std::unique_ptr<int>&>::type {aka std::unique_ptr<int>}’
    return std::move(t);
```

So, I needed a real rvalue reference as return type. At first, I didn't know how to construct it but finally, I figured out is that I first need to `std::remove_reference` the type `T` and then add `&&`, then I will have a real rvalue reference `T&&`. And it worked, this version of `mov` compiles fine and solves the problem:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& mov(T&& t){
   return std::move(t);
}
```

As Niall stated, returning by reference also works by using `remove_reference` without `&&`:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::remove_reference<T>::type mov(T&& t){
   return std::move(t);
}
```

Comment: Would making the return type `typename std::remove_reference<T>::type` also work?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Yes, it does. But I rly dunno why

Comment: @Mehrdad Just saw your comment, sync typing... the return-by-value here was hinted in the original question.

Comment: @gexicide: It works because the move construction happens inside the function rather than outside, and then the resulting move from the rvalue output is either elided or re-moved into the outer variable.